# Bring Git branch to state of commit in other branch

Tags: git, merge, version-control, branch

Assuming I have 2 branches A (the old one) and B (the new one), that recently separated. In A2 I have done some mistake (destroying the history of some files, that I wanted to keep), that I fixed with B2.

I want to bring the working directory of branch B to the state of commit A3, but do not merge/commit it. Instead, I would prefer having just the (staged/unstaged) local changes so that after the next commit, B3 will be identically to A3 (but not linked to A2 or A3 in any way):

```
A1 - [A2 - A3 - A4]  (A will be deleted after the fix)
   \
     B2 - B3=(state of)A3 - A4
```

The reason to do so in my case was that I messed up the intermediate state A2, which I wanted to fix with B2, and then continue directly with A3.

The easiest way that comes in my mind would be to checkout A3 in another folder, delete the contents of B and overwrite with the contents of A3.

Is there a Git command to achieve this directly?

Comment: Upvoted. I'm here because my forked repo on a git* service won't let me force push to my main branch, which has diverged (by mistake) from the upstream main branch.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The new (since Git 2.23) `git restore` command can do this as a single command, using `git restore --source commit --worktree -- .` from the top level of your working tree.  Since this kind of `git restore` does not affect Git's index, nothing here is staged.  But this is a very odd thing to *want*, so be very sure it's really what you want, before you do it.

(Adding `--staged` to the `git restore` above makes everything staged-for-commit as well.  Note that this is different from `git checkout commit -- .` as `git restore` runs in "no-overlay" mode by default, while `git checkout` uses "overlay" mode.)

Note that this does not bring any *branch* to any state.  Branches **do not have** this kind of state: branch names just identify commit hash IDs.  This `git restore` command simply modifies the contents of your *working tree* to match the specified commit, leaving the index / staging-area alone.  A subsequent `git commit` uses whatever is in Git's index, so you will have to run `git add` to affect that subsequent commit.

Answer (score 0):

@torek's answer worked for me and they clearly know git better than me.

If you just want a branch B to be coming off A3, you can `git checkout B; git reset --hard A3` which gives you:

```
A1 - A2 - A3 - A4
  \        \
   \        B
[   B2 - B3        ] These will get removed eventually; are no longer on a branch
```

If you want to keep the commit `B2` in the `B` branch's history, then you have a couple of options:

### Option 1

just create a new branch "abandoned-b-branch", then do the above. It means you'll always have that abandoned-b-branch to refer to if you need it.

### Option 2

```
git checkout B
git revert -n B2
git merge -n A3  # or even use cherry-pick -n
```

Which leaves your working tree at `A3`, but your `B2` commit as-was and still coming off of `A1`.

### Edit 1 - addressing clarified question

I set up the same scenario

```
* a3420df        (branch-A) A4
* e8b5e69        A3
* 3f9837f        A2
| * 1465593      (branch-B) B2
|/
* 6835b02        A1
```

- Commit `A1` just has one file, `A1`
- Commit `A2` added `A2`
- Commit `A3` added `A3` and deleted `A2`
- Commit `A4` added `A4`
- Commit `B2` added `B2`

Your updated question says you want

```
A1 - [A2 - A3 - A4]  (A will be deleted after the fix)
   \
     B2 - B3=(state of)A3 - A4
```

I did this:

```
git checkout branch-B
git revert -n 1465593
git cherry-pick -n 3f9837f e8b5e69
```

Which left the working tree in the state of `A3`, with files `A1` and `A3`. I could then continue to commit that as B3, then apply A4

```
git commit -m "B3"
git cherry-pick -n a3420df
git commit -m A4
```

Leaving me with branch-B (the final one) looking like

```
* 262a312        (HEAD -> branch-B) A4
* 7bca645        B3
* 1465593        B2
* 6835b02        A1
```

in the working tree I have A1, A3, A4. Commit `A2` is gone from my branch's history, but I still have B2 in my history.

Comment: I think you misunderstood me. I want to keep B2 but completely delete A2 - it never existed in branch B, but afterwards continue with A3 and A4. When I'm doing a Merge/Cherry Pick with branche A, the commit A2 will now be in the history of B.

Comment: So nothing to do with B? As in B branch is `A1 - B2` (as now) and you want A branch to be `A1 - A3 - A4` ?

Comment: Finally, I want to have one branch A1 - B2 - A3 - A4. The other one will be deleted. I simply want to replace A2 by B2 and then continue as if A2 never existed.